# image pull backoff for argo image in pod init

Tags: docker, argo-workflows

I have an issue when running argo workflows at some scale. Some pods go into a pod initializing state indefinitely and when i look at the events its because the argo-exec image cannot be fetched due to rate limits pulling the docker image from the same IP/anonymous user. I am not sure how to get around this.

How might i get around this?

1. is it possible/advised to keep the argo docker image in my own repository (maybe updating a controller config map to point to it) or
2. is there a way to manage authenticated docker access when pulling the image. The latter does not seem like a solution though as it might just mean I have more of a quota but it is still limited.
3. It seems that it should not be necessary to keep pulling this image anyway so maybe there is something in config where i can control this?? This last option seems ideal if so.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your answer - starting with the last one.

---

**Question 3:**

> It seems that it should not be necessary to keep pulling this
> image anyway so maybe there is something in config where i can control
> this??

**Answer:**

The docker registry that you're pulling from probably has a rate limit.

I would suggest you to do the same as you would do in Docker/K8s - use the `imagePullPolicy` field.

Check out the argo workflow docs under the [container spec](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/fields/#container).

An example:

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  name: daemon-nginx
spec:
  entrypoint: daemon-nginx-example

  templates:
  - name: daemon-nginx-example
    steps:
    - - name: nginx-server
        template: nginx-server

  - name: nginx-server
    daemon: true
    container:
      image: nginx:1.13
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent # <---- Here
      readinessProbe:
        httpGet:
          path: /
          port: "80"
        initialDelaySeconds: 2
        timeoutSeconds: 1
```

---

**Question 1:**

> is it possible/advised to keep the argo docker image in my own
> repository (maybe updating a controller config map to point to it)

**Answer:**

Not mandatory in order to solve the rate limit issue.

---

**Question 2:**

> is there a way to manage authenticated docker access when pulling
> the image..

**Answer:**

In the same link I shared - check out the `imagePullSecrets` option.

If you're not familar with this concept in K8S - I suggest that you read [Pull an Image from a Private Registry](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/).

Answer (score 0):

Question 1:

I found an command line option to specify 'executor-image'.
You can edit it in argo workflow-controller Deployment.

An example:

```
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: workflow-controller
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - --namespaced
        - --executor-image=yourhost.io/argoproj/argoexec:latest
        command:
        - workflow-controller
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).